# how to save comboxitems using project settings in c#

Tags: c#

I want to save my `ComboBox` items so that after closing the window application i restore previous items in `ComboBox` which i saved. I Declare Combobox item in project setting of type `system.collection.specialized.stringcolection`. my code for  is given below.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.combox);
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{  
     ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(this.comboBox1.Items);
     Properties.Settings.Default.combox = arraylist;   
}
```

but it show error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to
>   'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection'

Answer (score 1):

Get your items from settings and check if they're *null*. If they're not null, add them to your `ComboBox.Items` collection.

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboboxItems = Properties.Settings.Default.ComboboxItems;
    if (comboboxItems != null)
        comboBox.Items.AddRange(comboboxItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
}
```

When form is closing you need to put your items inside `StringCollection` format if you're willing to save them. So convert items from your `ComboBox.Items` collection to string array and add them inside `StringCollection`. Place your fresh collection into `Settings.Default` and important thing, don't forget to save changes.

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var comboboxItems = new StringCollection();
    comboboxItems.AddRange(comboBox.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
    Properties.Settings.Default.ComboboxItems = comboboxItems;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `Form1_FormClosing` method:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection items =
    new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
items.AddRange(this.comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
Properties.Settings.Default.combox = items;
```